# How to create a simple fragment shader that maps color from a lookup table?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to create image filters like Instagram for my Android application. I am new to image processing and have just stumbled upon this term called color mapping. After many research, I tried to create my own filter using OpenGL using a lookup table (LUT). But upon adding the filter to a camera, Here is the result:

[image]

You can see that there is this weird blueish color at the edge of my thumb. It only happens on overexposed areas of the image.

Here is the **fragment shader code:**

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision lowp float;
             
varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
             
uniform samplerExternalOES inputImage;
uniform sampler2D lookup;
             
void main() {
     vec2 tiles    = vec2(8.0);
     vec2 tileSize = vec2(64.0);
     vec4 texel = texture2D(inputImage, vTextureCoord);
     float index = texel.b * (tiles.x * tiles.y - 1.0);
     float index_min = min(62.0, floor(index));
     float index_max = index_min + 1.0;

     vec2 tileIndex_min;
     tileIndex_min.y = floor(index_min / tiles.x);
     tileIndex_min.x = floor(index_min - tileIndex_min.y * tiles.x);
     vec2 tileIndex_max;
     tileIndex_max.y = floor(index_max / tiles.x);
     tileIndex_max.x = floor(index_max - tileIndex_max.y * tiles.x);

     vec2 tileUV = mix(0.5/tileSize, (tileSize-0.5)/tileSize, texel.rg);
            
     vec2 tableUV_1 = tileIndex_min / tiles + tileUV / tiles;
     vec2 tableUV_2 = tileIndex_max / tiles + tileUV / tiles;
            
     vec3 lookUpColor_1 = texture2D(lookup, tableUV_1).rgb;
     vec3 lookUpColor_2 = texture2D(lookup, tableUV_2).rgb;
     vec3 lookUpColor   = mix(lookUpColor_1, lookUpColor_2, index-index_min);
     gl_FragColor = vec4(lookUpColor, 1.0);
}
```

Here is the lookup table. This is a base lookup table. I tried editing the lookup tables and applying the filter but the result is same, irrespective of the table. 
[image]

What is causing this issue? Can anyone show me how to create a simple fragment shader that maps color from lookup table to the current texture? Any help would be appreciated. Regards.

Here is the code for loading the textures:

```
public static int loadTexture(final Bitmap img) {
        int[] textures = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, img, 0);
        return textures[0];
    }
```

Comment: I just calculated the result for some values, but the math doesn't look correct. For example for rgb=[1,1,1]: index=63, index_min=63, index_max=64, tileIndex_min=[8,7], tileIndex_max = [0, 8] (<-- wrap around), tileUV = [0,9921875, 0,9921875], table_UV_1 = [1,1240234375, 0,9990234375] (<-- outside of texture). Since I'm not sure what your filter is actually supposed to do, I'm not sure if this is itended, but I guess it's wrong.

Comment: Oh sorry that was another mistake. You see all this code were in a String so it had many double quotes, line breaks and other special characters. I had to take everything out while posting it on stackoverflow so it can be easier to read hence the errors.  Thank you.

Comment: The shader works fine, except when a color channel of the texture is > 1. What is the format of the texture? Does something change if you change the precision from `precision lowp float;` to `precision highp float;`?

Comment: I changed the precision to highp but the result is same. As for the format I do not know because the OpenGL stuffs are done by this library : https://github.com/natario1/Egloo/

Comment: Does anything change if you try `vec4 texel = clamp(texture2D(inputImage, vTextureCoord), 0.0, 1.0);`?

Comment: No the result is still the same.

Comment: What are the texture parameters for the lookup texture? Are you accidentally generating mipmaps?

Comment: I have added the code for loading the texture. As for the mipmaps, I do not know. As I said, the library handles all that work.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? I'm surpirsed `tiles` in the shader is `8` given the image contains 64 (8x8)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what color space or gamma your external sampler is using, but it looks like you are getting input values outside of the zero-to-one range, so the over exposed areas are jumping a LUT tile boundary.

As a diagnostic, clamp your inputs between zero and one, but this is rarely the right "proper fix" as the clipping in the colors will be obvious.

Something like this:

```
     vec4 texel = texture2D(inputImage, vTextureCoord);
     texel = min(texel, 1.0);
```

Comment: I am sorry I am very new to OpenGL. This is a github library that I am using so I don't know what is happening behind the scene.  The library takes care of all that work and the only thing that I can change is the fragment and vertex shader.  So where should I begin exactly?

Comment: I tried clamping the the inputs tableUV_1 and tableUV_2 but the issue persists.

Comment: Clamp the output of the initial `texture2D()` call - example in the description.

Comment: Thank you so much but the result hasn't changed significantly.  There are still these small colorations as in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOUZK.jpg . You can see that the text have these weird outline. I tried applying different filters on the base lut and some of them were better than the other now using your suggestion. I am really curious to know why all this happens. Regards.